# Is there any security risk with a LUKS-encrypted hard drive being improperly unmounted?

Tags: luks

I have a portable harddrive that is encrypted with LUKS. On a computer I use it on, the computer bugs out sometimes and won't let me unmount it correctly. If the computer is powered off without a shutdown, or if the mounted HD is simply unplugged, is there any risk to the encryption on the disk, as in, could the keys be recovered more easily or would any data be partially decrypted or something?

I know there's a risk of data corruption, but I'm asking specifically about the security of the encrypted data after a sudden disconnection of the encrypted disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LUKS wont't write any unencrypted data to your encrypted partition. The keys are protected by locking them into RAM so they are not persisted.
I would pay attention to all non-encrypted partitions you have got. Make sure you wipe files instead of deleting them, and also wipe the free space of your unencrypted drives regularly to make sure they don't contain any unwanted leftovers. Also make sure your swap partition is encrypted if you use one. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Swap_encryption